# Why did the server remove database content created through Java Persistence API and how to prevent it?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, insert, wildfly, java-ee-7

I am new in Java EE and today I used JPA for the first time.
I created a Java web app and deployed it to Openshift cloud on a Wildfly server using this tutorial:
https://blog.openshift.com/build-and-deploy-cloud-aware-java-ee-6-postgresql-92-applications-inside-eclipse/

I have no idea why the server removed all inserted data, when I changed something in the app and turned off the server. How to prevent it? I want to insert data permanently, not for only one server session.

I used this function to insert data in the database:

```
public Foo insertFooToDatabase(Foo foo) {
            entityManager.persist(foo);
            return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`in persistence.xml is set to `create`. For more information see [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)